# how to get object of enumeration

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, enumeration

Im importing some data from JSON ,

i have the values in a enumeration of an NSString with dictionaries

> ```
>       for (status in statuses)  //status is a dictionary and statuses is the JSON array
>    {
>     // You can retrieve individual values using objectForKey on the status NSDictionary
>     NSLog(@"status = %@",status);
> }
> ```

so it shows all the status objects,
but how can I show just one, with the index?
cant understand yet the line `// You can retrieve individual values using objectForKey on the status NSDictionary`

thanks a lot

Comment: id object = [myDictionary objectForKey: @"key1"]; can be called if you know what the key is; in my example it's an NSString. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDictionary maps one object (`key`) to another(`value`). When you want to get what value is mapped to some object (`key`), you should call `[yourNSDictionaryObject objectForKey:key];`

In your example you should call `[statuses objectForKey:yourStatusValue];`